# Spaces in html select options

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I want to make something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Column1abc     Column2klmn       Column3</option>
    <option>Column1defgh   Column2opr        Column3</option>
    <option>Column1ij      Column2stuvwxyz   Column3</option>
</select>
```

with `<style>select option { font-family: courier;} </style>`

But the rendered result is without multiple spaces.

If I use `&nbsp;` instead of "", I get `&nbsp;` as string, not as non-breaking space.

How can I fix that?

Comment: `&nbsp;` works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XPxMZ/. Note that I've put the styling on the `select` element rather than `select option`.

Comment: Strange, in clean HTML it works, but not in html.twig in Symfony.

Comment: Looks like Symfony is escaping the option contents (turning `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;`).

Comment: So, Symfony is Troller...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that Twig will automatically escape HTML entities (calling `htmlspecialchars`, effectively). Since you want to send a literal string of HTML, you don't want the automatic escaping to be done.

Now, you haven't provided your Twig code, so I can't say exactly how you should do this. But my guess is that you're including it with something like this:

```
{{ table.column }}
```

You need to use the [`raw` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html):

```
{{ table.column | raw }}
```

You do need to be careful here, though. If the values in the column can come from a user, you're opening yourself up to an XSS attack.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` works !!!!

```
<select>
    <option>Column1abc   &nbsp;  Column2klmn   &nbsp;    Column3</option>
    <option>Column1defgh  &nbsp; Column2opr    &nbsp;    Column3</option>
    <option>Column1ij    &nbsp;  Column2stuvwxyz &nbsp;  Column3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. HTML code is in html.twig file.

Answer (score -2):

```
//use code
select{word-spacing:1px;}
```

Comment: maybe you could add some explanation to your answwer, specifically how it resolves the problem. The idea is to provide a little teaching ...

Comment: It's amazing how wrong a single-line answer can be. Firstly, you can't style native dropdowns with CSS. Secondly, the OP wants variable spacing depending on the string lengths, so that each column lines up. This does not do that. And finally, `word-spacing:1px;` would just add one pixel between each word -- a difference so small it's hard to even notice.